# juju error: hook failed: "config-changed"

Tags: juju, maas

I am deploying ha ha cluster for keystone, cluter is up and both units are showing agent state "Started" but one unit is showing error as "error: hook failed: "config-changed"
I sshed to that unit and chekec keystone logs also there are no errors, and config also looks ok, So whats the error here? I mean how i am suppose to troubleshoot it?
Here is output of juju status,

```
keystone:
    charm: local:precise/keystone-223
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - keystone
      ha:
      - keystone-hacluster
      identity-service:
      - cinder
      - glance
      - nova-cloud-controller
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      keystone/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "config-changed"'
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "12"
        public-address: opks02.master
        subordinates:
          keystone-hacluster/1:
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.12.0
            public-address: opks02.master
      keystone/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "13"
        public-address: opks01.master
        subordinates:
          keystone-hacluster/0:
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.12.0
            public-address: opks01.master
  keystone-hacluster:
    charm: local:precise/hacluster-67
    exposed: false
    relations:
      ha:
      - keystone
      hanode:
      - keystone-hacluster
    subordinate-to:
    - keystone
```

Comment: Are you sure `opks02.master` is routeable?

Comment: yes i can ssh it. and i also viewed all config and logs

Answer (score 7):

If you verified there are no obvious errors, you can always retry running the hook to see if it resolves the issue:

`juju resolved --retry keystone/0`

If the problem still persists, you could try:

`juju debug-hooks keystone/0 config-changed`,

which will SSH into the machine and wait for the `config-changed` to run. You need to manually trigger the hook outside by running `resolved` as described above. Once the hook  starts you can run the hook script manually, inspect its output or relation settings, or change what the hook does, interactively.

You should also check out the documentation on [Hook errors](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-hook-errors.html), and [Hook debugging](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-hook-debug.html)